# Norm of an operator is $0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let , $T$ be a operator such that $\Vert T \Vert = 0$, then do we have $T = 0$ ? I am having some doubts with this. If this is not the case then could you give an example.

My thoughts so far. We have $\displaystyle \Vert T \Vert = \underset{x \neq 0}{\sup}\frac{\Vert Tx \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert}$. So, if $\Vert T \Vert$ =  $0$. Then, we must have $\Vert Tx \Vert = 0$ for $x \neq 0$. What can I conclude from here ?

Comment: Your question would benefit hugely from showing some of your thoughts and why they create doubts!  As it stands this is little more than a bare question and goes against the quality standards of the site -- so is liable to be closed to allow you time to improve it.  (See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards for quality standards).  Why not start by writing out the definition of the operator norm and explaining how you think it can be $0$ when $T$ is non-zero?

Comment: Usually in functional analysis and other theories revolving around metric spaces, the term "norm" refers to functions that satisfy (some properties and) the axiomatic property of being $0$ in $0$ and strictly positive on non-zero elements. For addressing this case specifically, we would need the relevant definitions.

Comment: Well, what is the definition of $\|T\|$?

Comment: @ArcticChar I have made an edit to my post.

Comment: Note that $\|Tx\| = 0$ if and only if $Tx = 0$.

Comment: @Gae.S. ??? The definition of the norm of an operator is absolutely standard.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well... so is the fact that it's a norm.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yes, the fact that it's a norm is very standard. How does it follow that "For addressing this case specifcally, we would need the relevant defintions"?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Because it might not be what he's talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably benefit from expressing things in a clearer way. What you have is a normed space $X$. For a linear map $T:X\to X$, you define a norm by
$$
\|T\|=\sup\Big\{\frac{\|Tx\|_X}{\|x\|_X}:\ x\in X,\ x\ne0\Big\}.
$$
From $\|T\|=0$, as you say you get that $\|Tx\|=0$ for each $x\in X$. By definition of norm, this implies that $Tx=0$ for each $x\in X$. In the end you have a function $T$ that takes the value $0$ at every point; that's the function we denote by zero.

If you are confused by this, make sure that you understand that in the equalities $\|T\|=0$, $Tx=0$, and $T=0$, the three zeroes are different objects.